# scale up small uploaded images in drupal 7 imce

Tags: media, files

I have many image size Thumbnails defined in [**imce**](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) module.

whenever a very small image (smaller than any of my thumbnail) is uploaded, imce does not scale up it to make a bigger thumbnail than the actual size and it make trouble for me.

how can I make all thumbnails for big or small images?
hope explaining clearly.

Comment: may I know how you display your images? example: views, wysiwyg etc...

Comment: by views. I've solve it. i will post the answer soon